# How to put 'null' results to back in descending order in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to ORDER BY in Cypher to put 'null' results to back in descending sort? By [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/order-by/) null results come as the first in descending sort.

```
MATCH (n:Title) 
WHERE n.primaryTitle STARTS WITH "D"
RETURN n.primaryTitle, n.startYear, n.ratings, n.numberOfVotes 
ORDER BY n.numberOfVotes DESC 
LIMIT 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `coalesce` the nulls to zero in the `ORDER BY`.

```
MATCH (n:Title) 
WHERE n.primaryTitle STARTS WITH "D"
RETURN n.primaryTitle, n.startYear, n.ratings, n.numberOfVotes 
ORDER BY coalesce(n.numberOfVotes,0) DESC 
LIMIT 7
```

OR you could simply coalesce the returned attribute.

```
MATCH (n:Title) 
WHERE n.primaryTitle STARTS WITH "D"
RETURN n.primaryTitle, n.startYear, n.ratings, coalesce(n.numberOfVotes,0) 
ORDER BY n.numberOfVotes DESC 
LIMIT 7
```